# TensorFlow Multivariable Linear Regression: Always Predicts 0 - What have I missed?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, linear-regression

I have a dataset that I'm trying to fit a linear regression model to. When I run it, it predicts 0 for all inputs which makes me think I've done something wrong training it, rather than the outputs should all be 0.

My data looks like this:

```
Year  Month  Day  DayOfWeek  Hour  Minute  RegisteredUsers  Temperature
2017    8    30       4       21    10        137539            16.8
2017    8    30       4       21    20        137539            16.8
2017    8    30       4       21    30        137539            16.8
2017    8    30       4       21    40        137539            16.8
2017    8    30       4       21    50        137539            16.8
```

And I have a target for each row:

```
Target
 1.25
 1.25
 2.50
 3.00
 1.25
```

The code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

seed = 128
rng = np.random.RandomState(seed)

# Load Training Data
train_x = get_training_data()
train_y = get_training_targets()

# Build Graph
n_features = train_x.shape[1]

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_features])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])

w = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_features, 1]), name="w")
b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[]), name="b")

h = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, w), b)

batch_size = 1000
epochs = 5000
learning_rate = 0.2

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.subtract(y, h)), name="cost")
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(init)

    # Train
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        avg_cost = 0.
        total_batch = int(train_x.shape[0]/batch_size)

        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch_x, batch_y = batch_creator(batch_size, train_x.shape[0], 'train')
            sess.run([cost, optimizer], feed_dict = {x: batch_x, y: batch_y})

        if (epoch + 1) % 1000 == 0:
            print "Epoch", (epoch + 1), "complete."

    print "Training complete!"

    # Load Test Data
    test_x = get_test_data()
    test_y = get_test_targets()

    # Check Accuracy
    pred_temp = tf.equal(h, y)
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(pred_temp, "float"))
    print "Validation Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({x: test_x.values, y: test_y.values})

# Prepare batches
def batch_creator(batch_size, dataset_length, dataset_name):
    batch_mask = rng.choice(dataset_length, batch_size)
    batch_x = eval(dataset_name + '_x').values[[batch_mask]]
    batch_y = eval(dataset_name + '_y').values[[batch_mask]]    
    return batch_x, batch_y
```

Running it outputs:

```
Epoch 1000 complete.
Epoch 2000 complete.
Epoch 3000 complete.
Epoch 4000 complete.
Epoch 5000 complete.
Training complete!
Validation Accuracy: 0.0
```

I wondered if the column of `RegisteredUsers` which is much larger than the other columns might have been skewing the data slightly, but ignoring it for the time being gives the same results.

Any suggestions for what I should try to get meaningful results?

---

#### Edits from Comments

I've reduced the batch size to 128 and used 5 epochs. Instead of determining accuracy, I'm outputting the cost after each epoch:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(init)

    for epoch in range(epochs):
        avg_cost = 0.
        total_batch = int(train_x.shape[0]/batch_size)

        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch_x, batch_y = batch_creator(batch_size, train_x.shape[0], 'train')
            c, _ = sess.run([cost, optimizer], feed_dict = {x: batch_x, y: batch_y})

        print "Epoch", epoch, ": cost = ", c

    print "Training complete!"
```

The output is:

```
Epoch 0 : cost =  9.60435e+08
Epoch 1 : cost =  3.88509e+08
Epoch 2 : cost =  6.77093e+07
Epoch 3 : cost =  1.84114e+07
Epoch 4 : cost =  1.18253e+07
Training complete!
```

Thoughts?

Comment: You should print the loss after every epoch to make sure it is decreasing. Also you have to tune the number of epochs and specially the learning rate. Using accuracy for a regression problem makes no sense.

Comment: try reducing the batch size to 32/64/128. Also number of epoch seems too high and you need to stop the training when loss is stopped changing between epochs. May be reduce epochs to 4 or 5.

Comment: Try reducing your batch size and also using `tf.train.AdamOptimizer` with default settings instead of SGD.